Какую библиотеку выбрать, чтобы написать скрипт, который отправляет сообщения от лица пользователя боту в телеграм?
Пишу ботов на aiogram 3. Встал вопрос о написании бота или скрипта, который будет отправлять сообщения и взаимодействовать с другим ботом. Есть бот для резервации парковочных мест и ровно в 18:00 он выкладывает список свободных мест. Нужен бот или скрипт, который в 18:01 будет от лица пользователя бронировать одно место.
Я так поняла, что это возможно сделать через какую-то библиотеку или API. Если кто-то уже писать что-то подобное прошу поделиться опытом и посоветовать библиотеку.

С помощью aiogram не получится т.к. одни боты не могут писать другим, соответственно нужен юзер-бот. Для юзер ботов можно использовать библиотеку pyrogram

Тогда вопрос. Насколько безопасно привязывать юзер бота к своему аккаунту в телеграм? Слышала у них не очень хорошая репутация тк недобросовестные разработчики часто политику нарушали, поэтому банят часто. Или лучше перестраховаться и создать новый аккаунт?

На моём опыте если не нарушать политику, то не банят. Если сильно переживаете то, можете, конечно, создать аккаунт.

pyrogram и иже с ними библиотеки для написания своих клиентов, если вы будете использовать это для того, что описали - это уже нарушение ToS
